# Infinite get /json when starting express app

Tags: node.js, express, npm

My question might be very stupid as I'm totally new in web development and nodejs.

I followed the express explanations here -> http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

which indicate how to generate an application skeleton. 
Once I launch the app I look at the shell and I have an infinite message 
GET /json 404 : [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6BvX.jpg)
I'm not requesting any url yet (other than the http://localhost:3000/) so it confuses me.
I got this issue right after doing the express tutorial steps (cf link above). After trying different methods (setting the port listening in the app, running via node inspect, etc.) I still get the same message as it was an infinite loop. Is this normal ? Maybe this article answers my question : http://jilles.me/getting-the-express-app-js/ (section named "The Special 404 Error") where it seems that 404 does not necessarily mean an error.

Nonetheless, I would like to be 100% sure this is ok so that I don't start programming with errors from the start.

Thanks very much in advance for your help.

Please see below the code generated by express :

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

// These lines are mines but they haven't solved the issue
/* ------------------------------------------------- */
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000); 

var server = app.listen(app.get('port')); 
/* ------------------------------------------------- */

module.exports = app;
```

And here is the 'http-errors' module if needed :

```
/*!
 * http-errors
 * Copyright(c) 2014 Jonathan Ong
 * Copyright(c) 2016 Douglas Christopher Wilson
 * MIT Licensed
 */

'use strict'

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 * @private
 */

var deprecate = require('depd')('http-errors')
var setPrototypeOf = require('setprototypeof')
var statuses = require('statuses')
var inherits = require('inherits')

/**
 * Module exports.
 * @public
 */

module.exports = createError
module.exports.HttpError = createHttpErrorConstructor()

// Populate exports for all constructors
populateConstructorExports(module.exports, statuses.codes, module.exports.HttpError)

/**
 * Get the code class of a status code.
 * @private
 */

function codeClass (status) {
  return Number(String(status).charAt(0) + '00')
}

/**
 * Create a new HTTP Error.
 *
 * @returns {Error}
 * @public
 */

function createError () {
  // so much arity going on ~_~
  var err
  var msg
  var status = 500
  var props = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var arg = arguments[i]
    if (arg instanceof Error) {
      err = arg
      status = err.status || err.statusCode || status
      continue
    }
    switch (typeof arg) {
      case 'string':
        msg = arg
        break
      case 'number':
        status = arg
        if (i !== 0) {
          deprecate('non-first-argument status code; replace with createError(' + arg + ', ...)')
        }
        break
      case 'object':
        props = arg
        break
    }
  }

  if (typeof status === 'number' && (status < 400 || status >= 600)) {
    deprecate('non-error status code; use only 4xx or 5xx status codes')
  }

  if (typeof status !== 'number' ||
    (!statuses[status] && (status < 400 || status >= 600))) {
    status = 500
  }

  // constructor
  var HttpError = createError[status] || createError[codeClass(status)]

  if (!err) {
    // create error
    err = HttpError
      ? new HttpError(msg)
      : new Error(msg || statuses[status])
    Error.captureStackTrace(err, createError)
  }

  if (!HttpError || !(err instanceof HttpError) || err.status !== status) {
    // add properties to generic error
    err.expose = status < 500
    err.status = err.statusCode = status
  }

  for (var key in props) {
    if (key !== 'status' && key !== 'statusCode') {
      err[key] = props[key]
    }
  }

  return err
}

/**
 * Create HTTP error abstract base class.
 * @private
 */

function createHttpErrorConstructor () {
  function HttpError () {
    throw new TypeError('cannot construct abstract class')
  }

  inherits(HttpError, Error)

  return HttpError
}

/**
 * Create a constructor for a client error.
 * @private
 */

function createClientErrorConstructor (HttpError, name, code) {
  var className = name.match(/Error$/) ? name : name + 'Error'

  function ClientError (message) {
    // create the error object
    var msg = message != null ? message : statuses[code]
    var err = new Error(msg)

    // capture a stack trace to the construction point
    Error.captureStackTrace(err, ClientError)

    // adjust the [[Prototype]]
    setPrototypeOf(err, ClientError.prototype)

    // redefine the error message
    Object.defineProperty(err, 'message', {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
      value: msg,
      writable: true
    })

    // redefine the error name
    Object.defineProperty(err, 'name', {
      enumerable: false,
      configurable: true,
      value: className,
      writable: true
    })

    return err
  }

  inherits(ClientError, HttpError)

  ClientError.prototype.status = code
  ClientError.prototype.statusCode = code
  ClientError.prototype.expose = true

  return ClientError
}

/**
 * Create a constructor for a server error.
 * @private
 */

function createServerErrorConstructor (HttpError, name, code) {
  var className = name.match(/Error$/) ? name : name + 'Error'

  function ServerError (message) {
    // create the error object
    var msg = message != null ? message : statuses[code]
    var err = new Error(msg)

    // capture a stack trace to the construction point
    Error.captureStackTrace(err, ServerError)

    // adjust the [[Prototype]]
    setPrototypeOf(err, ServerError.prototype)

    // redefine the error message
    Object.defineProperty(err, 'message', {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
      value: msg,
      writable: true
    })

    // redefine the error name
    Object.defineProperty(err, 'name', {
      enumerable: false,
      configurable: true,
      value: className,
      writable: true
    })

    return err
  }

  inherits(ServerError, HttpError)

  ServerError.prototype.status = code
  ServerError.prototype.statusCode = code
  ServerError.prototype.expose = false

  return ServerError
}

/**
 * Populate the exports object with constructors for every error class.
 * @private
 */

function populateConstructorExports (exports, codes, HttpError) {
  codes.forEach(function forEachCode (code) {
    var CodeError
    var name = toIdentifier(statuses[code])

    switch (codeClass(code)) {
      case 400:
        CodeError = createClientErrorConstructor(HttpError, name, code)
        break
      case 500:
        CodeError = createServerErrorConstructor(HttpError, name, code)
        break
    }

    if (CodeError) {
      // export the constructor
      exports[code] = CodeError
      exports[name] = CodeError
    }
  })

  // backwards-compatibility
  exports["I'mateapot"] = deprecate.function(exports.ImATeapot,
    '"I\'mateapot"; use "ImATeapot" instead')
}

/**
 * Convert a string of words to a JavaScript identifier.
 * @private
 */

function toIdentifier (str) {
  return str.split(' ').map(function (token) {
    return token.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + token.slice(1)
  }).join('').replace(/[^ _0-9a-z]/gi, '')
}
```

Comment: Please provide the important parts of your code.

Comment: @wayneOS I've updated my question putting the code at the end of it.

Comment: Looking at the image you posted, it looks like you have a lot of browser tabs open.  I would guess one of them is open to `http://localhost:3000/` which is loading your web app which is then making ajax requests to `http://localhost:3000/json` to get data, which is a route that doesn't exist, hence 404.  Try closing the browser and restarting the node.js process.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks generalhenry for your help ! I had the DevTools automatically opened which was also open to the port 3000. I stopped it and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

it happens due to dev tools. when chrome or any other dev tools is listening to it or port forwarding configuration in dev tools.
Just close the dev tools and run it in dev mode instead of debug mode and it works like a charm :)

Comment: Why is it a problem? Before I didn't face with this kind of problem when dev tools were opened